Problem with installation of Quantum ESPRESSO in Ubuntu 20.04
While installing Quantum ESPRESSO, I encountered the following compilation errors related to type specifiers in /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/floatn-common.h:
bash

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/floatn-common.h(214): error: invalid combination of type specifiers
  typedef float _Float32;
                ^

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/floatn-common.h(251): error: invalid combination of type specifiers
  typedef double _Float64;
                 ^

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/floatn-common.h(268): error: invalid combination of type specifiers
  typedef double _Float32x;
                 ^

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/floatn-common.h(285): error: invalid combination of type specifiers
  typedef long double _Float64x;
                      ^

These errors occur during the compilation of copy.c, and I'm unsure how to resolve them. Could you please advise on what might be causing these errors and how to fix them?

+1. Welcome to our community.

+1 but what compiler are you using? I recommend to just change the compiler until you get it working, because Quantum ESPRESSO does compile on many systems.

How are you compiling it? I am asking since there are many ways to compile QE. Also, which version of QE are you using? Do you have all the prerequisites installed? (the prerequisites varies depending on the choice of libraries)

Is this with gcc13? Try gcc12 or gcc14 and later.
